# Почему не получается добавить в <Switch> Больше одного компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Использую react-router-dom@4.2.2
Начал делать проект при помощи create-react-app
Сделал главный Switch, который определяет какую страницу рендерить.
Приложение обёрнуто в BrowserRouter, Linkи работают, всё в шоколаде, кроме одного...
На одной из страниц есть контент, который отображается по разному.
Вот сам код:

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        exact
        path={`${this.props.match.path}`}
        component={SectionGallery} />
    <Route
        path={`${this.props.match.path}:product`}
        component={Putin} />
</Switch>
```

Названия роли не играют. Почему-то, когда я использую только 1 роут, то всё работает хорошо, при этом не важно какой и с каким path.

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        exact
        path={`${this.props.match.path}`}
        component={SectionGallery} />
</Switch>
```

Сама ошибка: A < Router > may have only one child element, без ссылок на конкретный участок кода. Чего он возмущается, ведь с < Router > всё хорошо...

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <Router>
            <main>
               <div className="page">
                   <Page />
                   <SocialLink />
               </div>
            </main>
        </Router>
      )
   }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Нихренашеньки не понял, я просто добавил в import Router, нигде не применяя на странице и оно заработало... Магия вне Хоргвардса, не иначе...

Когда я делал Link и они у меня не работали, я точно так же добавил в import Redirect и они запахали как миленькие... Как это работает?